# location of the "disk identifier"

Tags: fdisk

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), "disk signature" is a 32 bit value stored in MBR on bytes 440 - 443. According to `fdisk`, my "disk identifier" is *00043afc* in hex:

```
# fdisk -lu /dev/sda | grep identi
Disk identifier: 0x00043afc
#
```

However, I can not confirm this with `dd`:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda skip=439 bs=1 count=4 2>/dev/null | xxd -ps
c3fc3a04
#
```

Even if I check the entire MBR, I do not see the "disk identifier":

```
# dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | xxd -ps | grep 43a
#
```

Where is the "disk identifier" stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you found your answer with the first `dd` already. It's just in different endian order. Read the bytes (two-character hex sequences) reverse. And set the skip value to 440 instead of 439.